# Mekoros book for עוז והדר לבושה

Tags: product-recommendation, tznius-modesty

Throughout the work on Tzniut entitled *Oz VeHadar Levusha*, by R. Pesach Falk, he refers to a separate book of his entitled "*Mekorot*" which includes a more complete list of the sources he bases his ~700-page encyclopedia upon.

However, I have been unable to find any mention of this book online. Does anyone know where this book can be viewed or purchased? Or perhaps, it has still yet to be published?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4821/472).

Answer (score 8):

Based on some Internet research, it appears that the Sefer you are looking for is Levushah Shel Torah, available on Otzar Hachochma [here](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?154957). It is by the same author, and described as "sources and clarifications (Mekoros Uviurim) in Halacha and Aggadah to the Sefer "Oz Vehadar Levushah"

According to a quick Google search, it appears to be available in many seforim stores.

Comment: http://www.urimpublications.com/understanding-tzniut-modern-controversies-in-the-jewish-community.html

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Initially, I thought that לבושה של תורה was merely a Hebrew translation of the book.

Comment: @sam For those who don’t/won’t own the book, [here](http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/Henkin%20QX.1.pdf) is a different (free) article from the same author refuting various rulings of the aforementioned book, OVL.